# Is it possible to use slice in Python in list of complex objects with field of the object

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I am new in Python and using python3.
I have list og objects of type points

```
class Po:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

C = [Po(0, j) for j in range(10)]
```

and 2 dimensional array

```
m = [[j for i in range(2)] for j in range(10)]
```

I want to assign all fields x of C to values with index 0 from m like

```
C[:].x = m[:][0]
```

but python says list doesn't have field x.
how can I do this and why I can' access x this way

Comment: You are using Python 3; it's highly unlikely you are using 3.0 specifically.

Comment: `C` is a list of points. What do you want to do with it? Modify its x value?

Comment: `C[:]` refers to a list, `C[:].x` is trying to access the field `x` in the list, you will need to use a for loop or library that supports this kind of slicing for lists

Comment: `C[:]` is basically a shallow copy of `C`; `.` doesn't "distribute" over each element of that list.

Comment: particularly check what `m[:][0]` is doing, it isn't slicing a column like you are probably thinking it is. If you are coming from matlab you will probably be more comfortable working with `numpy` arrays that do support this kind of slicign but idk if it works for object fields as well.

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific syntax for this in Python. You'll just need to use a regular `for` loop.

```
for ci, mi in zip(C, m):
    ci.x = mi[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "C" instance is itself a list, so in order to access it's x or y values, you need to call the index first. So this way you can access them:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(C[i].x)
    print(C[i].y)
```